# Is it normal to feel rude if someone tells me “you might appreciate” in certain context?

Tags: connotations

There was a meeting that I did not attend due to my schedule. I made prior notification to my colleagues and they have accepted it.

My colleague said he will give me a “full” update of the work and later provided three lines of comments to me. I made my feedbacks accordingly.

Then this colleague told me

> ...That being the case, would you not agree that it would be rather unprofessional to make premature judgements as to our lines of investigation.

and then added

> ...you might appreciate and also welcome the fact that...

Then again

> .... you might also appreciate that...

He wants to say there has been more going on than I realized so that I should appreciate them instead.

In this context, I firstly felt I am being pushed/forced to appreciate something from them and felt uncomfortable. But not sure whether this is a right feeling

Is this something that I should feel upset or rude? Or is it a neutral tone?

Comment: You might appreciate...what?  That doesn't make sense just tacked onto the end like that.

Comment: @RyanM: Updated more.

Comment: @RyanM He wants to say there has been more going on than I realized so that I should appreciate him and their colleagues instead. The problems were miscommunication and information asymmetry instead. I clarified this later but my initial reaction was feeling uncomfortable. In this context, I felt being pushed/forced to appreciate something and felt uncomfortable. Is this the right feeling?

Comment: It really depends what he said you should appreciate.  If he said "you might appreciate that I'm even responding to you" or something, that would be quite rude.  If he said "you might appreciate that people don't make premature judgements of your work, and instead give it the credit it deserves" ...well, maybe it's a bit condescending.

Comment: @RyanM He was saying there are more investigations in their work than he initially told me in three lines. Thus I might appreciate the fact that much more work is being done and I should not be rather unprofessional to make premature judgements of what has been going on. But I thought whether to appreciate or not is my choice?

Comment: @RyanM So feeling “condescending” would be correct? If so I might have to make some formal complaints to this colleague.

Comment: @RyanM I did not attend their meeting because I could not find my time for that and made a prior notification. Then based on the three lines the colleague has provided I made some comments. Then this is how he is coming back.

Comment: @RyanM premature judgements of “their” works not mine as I did not attend..

Comment: @RyanM Ah no “you might appreciate” and “judgement to your own work” did not come into the same sentence at all. When he said “you might appreciate” it was only followed by the harder works that I did not realize. But give it a credit it deserves sounds correct.

Comment: IMHO, "you might appreciate" is quite a tactful way of indicating that your opinions seem somewhat ill-informed- which might well be true because you did not attend the meeting. Take it on the chin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't being asked to "appreciate them", but to appreciate, or take into account, something they have told you.

[American Heritage Dictionary "appreciate"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=appreciate)

> 2. To be fully aware of or sensitive to; realize: *I appreciate your problems.*

It's clear that they are correcting you, that they think you haven't been cognizant of something, that you may have made "premature judgments".

As to whether you should feel offended by that, it's up to you. Maybe they have good points to make, and you should take into account what they said. On the other hand, maybe they were unfair.

The usage in your title, "Is it normal to feel rude", isn't correct. You may feel that they have been rude to you.

Comment: Thank you. That clarifies more. Actually what I felt was that they have not done enough work given the timeframe, so initially my colleague only sent out three lines of updates. I made feedbacks on it to everybody. Then this is how he is coming back publicly. And he wants to say they are seriously considering this work more than I realized. But he made his full updates in three lines and I made feedbacks. Then this is how he is coming. He used to be is a person who likes to hide things in general and save his reputation more. It’s complicated to make my decision on the feelings I must have.